# Length of Numenera Starter Adventure

Tags: published-adventures, numenera

I recently purchased the [Numenera starter set](https://www.montecookgames.com/store/product/numenera-starter-set/). Although I don't have any experience with Numenera, the starter adventure looks very short. How long does it take to play through this adventure?

There is no title on the adventure (the book is called "Numenera Starter Set Book 2"). Within the text of the book it seems to be called *Vortex*. The adventure focuses on the PCs discovering a mysterious chamber (the *narthex*) and the yellow-robed sect that live within.

Comment: What's the title on the starter adventure? I don't have this starter set specifically, but myself or someone else may be able to find it in the other materials that are out.

Comment: I added some info about the adventure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Vortex](https://www.montecookgames.com/store/product/vortex/) adventure that you're describing was originally created in order to demo Numenera at conventions as the product launched.

The stand-alone PDF for Vortex contains two parts, and per the text, each part can stand separately and is intended to play as a several-hour session.  The first part contains the temple and cult that you mention; the second part involves a more dangerous and unstable complex that is accessed through the vortex in the first.

Actual play time always depends on your group and GM, and since this is a starter, how much time is put into exploration and getting used to mechanics.  Given the original use for cons though, no more than 2-3 hours on each part sounds right.

Comment: Better answer may come along - I admittedly have more experience with reading this particular RPG than playing it.

Comment: After playing through it I agree with your estimate.  Answer accepted.