# Is the Vortex the same as the adventure in the starter set?

Tags: published-adventures, numenera

I have a copy of the Numenera starter set. It comes with an (untitled) adventure which centers around the discovery of the *narthex* and the strange cult that dwells within.

The Monte Cook Games site has a cheap adventure for sale called [The Vortex](https://www.montecookgames.com/store/product/vortex/).

Is this the same adventure? Or not?

Reasons I think they might be the same thing:

- The cover art from *The Vortex* matches one of the illustrations in the starter set.
- This part of *The Vortex*'s description applies to the starter set as well: "explore the strange complex to find a missing boy"
- The answer to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/95655/length-of-numenera-starter-adventure) suggests they might be the same thing.

Reasons I think they might not be the same thing:

- This part of the description does not match the starter set, "[the adventure] might just take them unimaginably far from home".
- *The Vortex* is apparently set in two parts. The starter set is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I posted this same question on the Monte Cook Games Asset Team Chat page on Facebook. That page is used by MCG to communicate with volunteers who demo their products in stores.

Sean K. Reynolds confirmed that the starter set is indeed the first half of the Vortex adventure. Additionally, if you purchased the starter set there is a code that allows you to download the second half for free:

> **What's the relationship between the Vortex adventure and the Starter Set? The product descriptions sound similar, but not identical.**
>
> The NSS contains the first half of Vortex in print; when you get to the end of the first half, it directs you to a special link on the MCG site so you can download a free PDF of the second half.

[image]

The URL is on the inner-back cover of the adventure book (book 2).

Answer (score 3):

I do not have the starter set, but I do have Vortex. I looked up a youtube "unboxing" video and saw some familiar bits, then found a couple of references including this [review](http://rlyehreviews.blogspot.com/2017/01/a-numenera-mistarter.html), which state:

> Now if you are thinking, that scenario sounds awfully familiar, then
>   that is because it is. ‘Vortex’ in the ***Numenera Starter Set*** actually
>   turns out to be the first half of Vortex, the scenario that Monte Cook
>   Games used at GenCon 2013 to launch the game.

In addition, the Vortex adventure has six pregens, and the starter set only has five.